# Do we need to go in meta-theory for proving completeness?

Tags: logic, foundations, incompleteness

Do I need to go in some meta-theory A for proving theory B is complete ? Or can I do it inside the theory B ? If I really need it, what is the reason for that ?

Comment: Do You know Gödels theorems?

Comment: *Completeness* is a property of the theory: so, you need a context where to "speak of" the theory itself as a mathematical object and its properties. This context is caleld *meta-theory*.

Comment: @PeterMelech You are talking about Godel completness theorem's or incompletness theorems ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA OK, Then how Godel proved his completness theorems about first-order logic ?

Comment: See [Original proof of Gödel's completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_proof_of_G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem).